# Не сохраняются комментарии к постам из формы в базу данных SQLite в блоге на django

Tags: python, django

Делаю блог на django, возникла проблема при создании комментариев к постам. Через CBV создал класс AddCommentView. При создании комментария к чужому посту, сам комментарий не сохраняется в базу данных и не отображается под постом. При этом, если авторизованным пользователем создать комментарий к своему посту, то комментарий сохраняется. Не могу найти ошибку.

models.py:

```
class Comment(PublishedCreatedModel):
text = models.TextField('Текст комментария')
post = models.ForeignKey(
    Post,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='comments',

)
author = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='comments',
    verbose_name='Автор комментария'
)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'комментарий'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'
    ordering = ('created_at',)

def __str__(self):
    return f"Комментарий {self.author.username}"
```

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    exclude = ('author', 'is_published',)
    widgets = {
        'pub_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
    }

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ('text',)
```

urls.py:

```
path('posts/<int:post_id>/comment/',
     views.AddCommentView.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
```

views.py:

```
class AddCommentView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Comment
form_class = CommentForm
pk_url_kwarg = 'post_id'

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=kwargs['post_id'])
    if instance.author != request.user:
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', self.kwargs['post_id'])
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['post_id']
    existing_comment = Comment.objects.filter(
        author=form.instance.author,
        post=form.instance.post_id
    )
    if existing_comment.exists():
        raise ValidationError(
            "Вы уже оставили комментарий к данному посту"
        )
    return super().form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy(
        'blog:post_detail',
        kwargs={'id': self.kwargs['post_id']}
    )
```